# assertText on span with dynamic div

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver

Trying to find out how could I insert some text inside the span that has a dynamic div as a parent. the span has the price that is calculated after initial steps. I am really stuck with this.

I check the value of that span with `regexp:."*[1-9].*"`

[span inside a dynamic div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6DYX.png)

This option does not really work

```
//div[@class='gatsby-focus-wrapper']/main/div/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/span
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your Xpath is fragile and absolute. Did you try relative xpath?

Comment: You mean like // *[@class= ‘value ‘] ? I have tried to find out how I could add relative xpath, but I am beginner with testing. Maybe you have a suggestion on how I could find "amount" with relative xpath method?

Comment: Correct. If you can share web page URL, I can write better xpath. Based on screenshot its quite difficult.

Comment: Try this once : //span[@amount='14.03']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I can use "// *[@amount]". Cannot really use //span[@amount='14.03'] as the price is changing for every single user. But, suggestion did help. Thanks for the lift up folks :)